# Find the radius of the circle for given conditions

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

A circle with center at origin passes through three points $P$, $Q$ and $R$ with the line segment $PQ$ as its diameter along $x$-axis. A line passes through $P$ intersects the chord $QR$ at point $D$. The angle between the line segment $PD$ and $x$-axis is $\alpha$ and the distance between point $P$ and the midpoint of $DQ$ is $d$.

If $PD$ is the bisector of the angle RPQ then find the radius of the circle.

I took coordinates of $Q$ as $(a,0)$ and $P$ as $(-a,0)$.
Equation of PD will be $y=\tan\alpha(x+a)$.

So we can take coordinate of $D$ as $(h,\tan\alpha(h+a))$
If mid point of $DQ$ is $S$, then we get coordinates of $S$ in terms of $h,a,\alpha$ but how would be eliminate $h$ as radius is $'a'$ units and $\alpha$ is mentioned in the question, so we somehow need to eliminate $h$ to find radius in terms of $d$ and $\alpha$. How should I proceed?

Comment: The only way I can make sense of the question is if the point $\;D\;$ is interior to the circle (i.e. it is between $\;Q,\,R\;$ . Is that a given or I am missing something?

Comment: Would be simpler if you just remember that the *angle-to-centre* is the double of *angle-to-circumference*.

Comment: @Joanpemo Yes point $D$ is interior to the circle and lies on chord $QR$

Comment: @H.P.Das Try using the fact that angle subtended by diameter on circumference is $\frac{\pi}{2}$